# Roots producing isomorphic trees

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees, graph-isomorphism

Is there existing terminology for the following property of a rooted tree?

I'd like to know how many choices of root node can produce an isomorphic tree. This is different from the number of isomorphic trees. For example, consider this tree.

[image: tree on 7 nodes corresponding to Matula number 289]

If the node labeled '2' is the root, there are 4 total choices of root that produce isomorphic trees (2, 10, 8, and 15).

If 3 is the root, then there are 2 total choices that would produce isomorphic trees (3 or 12).

If 9 is the root, there is only one choice (9).

Is there a name, either for (a) this property of equivalence between roots, or (b) the number of nodes sharing this property?

Comment: the automorfism group of a graph splits the vertices into different orbits and you want to know if two leaves are in the same orbit. I tried to find if there was a name for when two vertices where in the same orbit a couple weeks ago and failed. I do know that graphs in which all vertices are in the same orbit are called transitive graphs (although this clearly wont happen for trees with more than $2$ vertices).

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it! Do you mind writing that up as an answer?

Comment: I can if you want but honestly I don't find that answer very satisfying. Maybe someone can say something better

Comment: Alright, I'll give it time.

Comment: This is somewhat related https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895677900454 . I also posted a question looking for more terminology https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4087494/is-there-a-term-for-when-two-elements-are-in-the-same-orbit-under-a-group-action .

Comment: @Jorge In some books on graph theory, two vertices (or two edges) of a graph are said to be *similar* if there is an automorphism of the graph that maps one to the other. This terminology is used in Frank Harary's *Graph Theory* except that Harary calls vertices and edges points and lines.